# How add a function to an object without memory inefficiency in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, object, memory

Suppose we have an object `foo`

```js
var foo = {
 x: 0
}
```

And we add a function `fx` to it like this:

```js
foo.fx = function() {do_something(this.x)}
```

If we do this process in a loop or in a function call for multiple times, does the JavaScript engine create that `fx` function multiple times or does it create the function for once and just change address of `this`?

e.g

```js
function objectMaker() {
     function fx() {
         this.x += 1; 
     } 

     var foo = {
        x: 0,
        fx: fx
     } 

     return foo;
}
```

Does the `objectMaker` function always allocate memory for `fx` method or does it create it only once?

Comment: I guess modern JS engines avoid wasting memory by recreating the same object multiple times, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: In your example with function I think that on each call of objectMaker new part of memory is allocated for fx https://jsfiddle.net/angkq8y7/1/

Answer (score 2):

Since functions are passed by reference (like arrays), if you declare the function once, you can assign it to multiple objects, without duplicating it.

In your `objectMaker` the `fx` function is redefined whenever you call the function. Extract `fx` out of the `objectMaker` (define once), and assign it to each created object.

```js
// define the function once
function fx() {
  return this.x += 1;
}

function objectMaker() {
  return {
    x: 0,
    fx
  }
}

var foo = objectMaker()
var bar = objectMaker()

console.log(foo.fx())
console.log(bar.fx())
console.log(foo.fx === bar.fx)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions also are objects. If you define a function inside another function's brackets, Javascript will create a new function every time the outer function was called.
If you want the function will be defined once, define it globally.

[image: 1. define a function inside other function]

[image: 2. define a function globally]

Answer (score 0):

Every call to objectMaker you are recreating the fx function. Move it outside to global scope so only one instance is created

Comment: function re-use has been allowed by the spec since v3.